# редирект при изменении домена и структуры

Tags: .htaccess

Всем хорошего дня!
Подскажите пожалуйста редирект при смене домена и структуры.
При изменении сайта возникла необходимость в дополнительной вложенности. теперь проблема сделать редирект с сохранением структуры урлов. старый сайта www.domen1.ru сайт новый www.domen2.ru.
нужен такой редирект чтобы получилось так
www.domen1.ru/tovar/ редиректил на www.domen1.ru/catalog/tovar/

то есть происходил редирект как бы во вложенную папку, а уже в ней структура идентична.
Спасибо всем, кто откликнется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Писал в уме, но похоже, что так :)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domen1\.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domen2.ru/catalog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: Я пробовал вот такой вариант. но редирект происходил только на domen2.ru без вложенности.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domen1\.ru$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domen2\.ru\/catalog\/" [R=301,L]

Comment: Но при Вашем варианте кода не происходит редирект главной страницы, а вот со структурой все отлично.
Можно ли как то объеденить и редирект на главную страницу т.е. domen1.ru/  ---> domen2.ru/catalog/

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domen2.ru/catalog/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Но при этом будут редиректиться и /smtng в /catalog/smtng